# Tests categorization

Tags: unit-testing, testing, nunit, categorization

I would like to know what's the "best practice" about categorizing tests using attributes (like the Category attribute of NUnit) ?

Do you categorize them by functionnal scope of the application, by kind (unit test, end-to-end tests, smoke tests, integration tests, etc), by technical category (long running, web request, etc) or a mix of each ?

To summarize, I don't want to re-categorize thousands of tests in few months, so what's the best strategy ?

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counter question: why do you want to categorize thousands of tests right now? What do you hope to accomplish. No need to do it at all if you don't know. :-)

My answer would be that Categories are really for the use of developers, because they can easily change them in the code when they need to. Sometimes, for example, it's handy to mark all the slow-running tests so they can be excluded from a run. You can mark all the fast running tests instead but one hopes there are many many more of them. Similarly, if you need to run tests when the database is not available, use categories on those tests that need it unless they are already grouped by namespace.

Use namespace grouping for your more permanent organization of tests. The power of categories is that they cut across your namespace and fixture organization. Use them sparingly when that sort of crosscutting is what you need but don't set up a rigid system of categories.

Comment: Actually it's just legacy code without test, I start to write them, so not thousands for the moment but soon :)

Comment: Categories may be useful to separate features of the ap, while developing, refactoring, fixing a bug in a feature you would want to run those test first to be on the safe zone before running all the tests which may be time consuming.

Comment: @SlavaShp, I affraid maintaining those categories will be difficult. Imagine you add category for tests you working with right now, then when finished and moved to another you need to remove Categories

Comment: @Fabio, The category shouldn't be 'testimworkingonrightnow' it should be something meaningful like the feature name of the feature you are working on, for example 'UserValidationOnRegistration' it's very specific and you can run only those

Comment: Now you talking about naming of tests. If you use categories for those, then you end up with thousand of categories. For example modern IDE:s, Visual Studio for example have possibility to run test from method under test

Answer (score 1):

Put integration test in different project. "WebRequest" tests is integration tests.

Idea of category to group tests which you can easily select and run.
Or exclude from running.
Based on that putting long running test in same category can be useful.

Most of IDE(Visual Studio at least) contain possibility to group tests by Class or by Project. So no needs using category for that.

NUnit console command-line support to include/exclude tests by category, so this can be useful in continuous delivery.